# Devise, Rails 5, custom errors for email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have Ajax registration with Rails 5 and Devise. This is `registrations_controller.rb`:

```
build_resource(sign_up_params)
byebug
    if resource.save
        if resource.active_for_authentication?
            sign_up(resource_name, resource)
            return render :json => {:success => true}
        else
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
            return render :json => {:success => true}
        end
    else
        return render :json => {:success => false}
    end
```

With `byebug` when I try to register with email that exist and debug with typing `resource.errors`, I see:

`<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00000007254a48 @base=#<User id: nil, email: "email@email.com", role_id: 0, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:email=>["has already been taken"]}, @details={:email=>[{:error=>:taken, :value=>"email@email.com"}]}>`

If I type in the console `resource.errors.messages`, I see this:

`{:email=>["has already been taken"]}`

I know how to get the message or set for the example:

```
if resource.errors.details[:email][0][:error] == :taken
     return render :json => {:error=> "Email already in use."}
end
```

or add in the model `user.rb`:

```
validate :email_uniqueness

def email_uniqueness
    self.errors.add(:email, 'Email is already in use') if User.where(:email => self.email).exists?
end
```

, but I want to change default error message. I searched in the whole project for this message, but found nothing.

How can I change error message in Devise, when email is already in use ?

Comment: Did you checkout the locale files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a default Rails validation error message. Read this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models

You can change the message in `*.en.yml` file like this:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              taken: is already in use
```